# Get record from 2 tables using PHP returning multiple results

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables. One called `local_requestors` and one called `local_aid`. They both have different sets of data, but they both share a column, the column in `local_requestors` called `suser_scheme` is the same as the data in the `local_aid` table column called `scheme_id`.

I want to query my tables to get all data from the `local_requestors` table, where the `ID` matches that of the row in the `local_aid` table.

I've used the following...

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * 
                        FROM local_requestors 
                            INNER JOIN local_aid 
                        WHERE local_requestors.user_scheme=local_aid.scheme_id 
                        AND local_requestors.id = :aid_id');

$stmt->execute(['aid_id' => $user_id]);
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo '<p>' . $row['user_name'] . '</p>';
}
```

This is all on a local page that I can only access, but to query the table I post some `$_GET[]` variables...

```
$user_id = $_GET['id'];
$scheme_id = $_GET['scheme_id'];
```

No matter what I try, I keep getting the same row from the `local_requestors` table, repeated around 10 times.

---

My goal is to get print the name of the user in the record from `local_aid` and a number of related records from `local_requstors`.

```
echo 'Hello ' . $aid_name . ', there is ' . $rowCount . ' people that need help in your area.;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have ment

```
SELECT * 
FROM local_requestors 
    INNER JOIN local_aid ON local_requestors.user_scheme=local_aid.scheme_id 
WHERE local_requestors.id = :aid_id
```

And from your description of what you want you may want a `LEFT JOIN` instead of a `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly, I've tried this but I'm still getting really strange results. I've changed my loop to show the names of the people in `local_aid` by using $row['user_name'], but I just get all of my users in that table.

I should get 1 user from local aid, and a count of all the related records from the local requestors table...

Comment: Liam, see the amended answer